# Fade-in effect for div without id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already made my website with flask. Posts are put on page by 'for' statement. The problem is each article is just with the same class, it doesn't have any id. I want to add some easy fade-in or opacity effect. Is there an easy way to do it without messing up code?

I'm not into JS, i watched some tutorials, but didn't find anything helpful. Each case was with using div with id.

```
{% for post in posts.items %}
<article class="media content-section">
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content[:300] }}... <hr /><small class="text-muted"><a href="{{ url_for('posts.post', post_id = post.id) }}">read more >></a></small></p>
  </div>
</article>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why not add an id to `<article>`? `<article class="..." id="post-{{post.id}}">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you're trying to stagger the fading in of the elements or not. Here is an example which staggers the fade.

```js
const articles = document.querySelectorAll('.media.content-section');

articles.forEach((article, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    article.classList.add('show');
  }, (index * 350))
});
```

```css
.media.content-section {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.media.content-section.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<article class="media content-section">
</article>

<article class="media content-section">
</article>

<article class="media content-section">
</article>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kfo1za3/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be including **animate.css library** in your project

[animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

and then just add **animated fadeIn** class to your article tag (or) any other tag you wish to add **fadeIn** effect.

```html
<article class="animated fadeIn">...</article>
```